# 2nd degree polynome instead of restricted cubic splines

Tags: splines, polynomial, rms

I am looking for an alternative to restricted cubic splines, which can provide a numerical result that is easier to interpret and compare (as far as I understand, this is not easily possible with splines - at least not when using `rcs` from the `rms` package.

The prediction-plot suggests that the association follows largely a 2nd degree polynomial equation - I therefore thought that using a second degree polynome, instead of `rcs`, would be an appropriate alternative. But is it?

Comment: It depends on why you're doing this and on the nature of your data. For instance, if you intend to use your fit to extrapolate or predict, then beware of any pure polynomial fit.  You're not using your model to calibrate a theoretical prediction, for otherwise you wouldn't contemplate splines at all: that makes one wonder what you really mean by "interpret."

Comment: The main reason to do this is to be able to facilitate the comparison of different models. I find it very difficult to compare two different graphs (e.g. whether curves are steeper or not etc) - whereas the polynomic parameters are much easier to interpret.

I don't want to use them instead of the splines, but rather as a help to interpret results.